How to match numbers in Spring Boot Path Pattern
I am using router function. I have a path like this. This product id will be a number always.
/{productId}

I am tryting to use these - none of them works.
RequestPredicates.path("\\d+")
RequestPredicates.path("[0-9]+")
However /250 is works fine with RequestPredicates.path("???")

You need to define name and regexp, similar way you do it in Spring Web:
@Component
public static class MyHandler {

    public Mono<ServerResponse> handleRequest(ServerRequest request) {
        var id = request.pathVariable("id");
        return ServerResponse.ok().bodyValue("Id is: " + id);
    }
}

@Bean
public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(MyHandler handler) {
    return RouterFunctions
            .route(path("/{id:[0-9]+}"), handler::handleRequest);
}


I appreciate you for taking time to answer..what is the point of RequestPredicates :(. I really want RequestPredicates to handle this!
